# How to run a query inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a query which is run inside foreach loop but it run only at once following code as mention below:

```
public function functional_job($functional)
    {
        $functions = explode(",",$functional);
        foreach($functions as $row)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('job');
            $this->db->where('functional',$row);
            $query = $this->db->get();if($query->num_rows()>0)
            {
                $result = $query->result_array();
                return $result;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<p style="color:red;font-weight: 600;">No Job Found.</p>');
            }
        }
    }
```

where `$functional = IT,marketing,ecommerce`. When I hit on the query it runs only one like `SELECT * FROM job WHERE functional = 'IT'`. but I want it run three times i.e. `SELECT * FROM job WHERE functional = 'IT' SELECT * FROM job WHERE functional = 'marketing' SELECT * FROM job WHERE functional = 'ecommerce'`

Comment: at present, if a result is returned the function will return this value and stop processing

Comment: You return at the first time you get some data `return $result;`.  Also use `IN` for your query and you will get all the results in 1 query. (something like `functional in( 'IT','marketing','ecommerce')`)

Comment: How can I use `IN` @NigelRen

Comment: As I'm not sure how you are fetching the data (are you using an ORM etc.) I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will return the value of one result and stop processing.

You could change your code to store the results in an array, and then return that?

```
public function functional_job($functional){

    $functions = explode(",",$functional);

    $results = array();

    foreach($functions as $row)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('job');
        $this->db->where('functional',$row);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            $results[] = $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<p style="color:red;font-weight: 600;">No Job Found.</p>');
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

As mentioned you could also alter your query to use the IN functionality of MySql.

```
SELECT * FROM job WHERE functional IN ('IT', 'marketing', 'ecommerce')
```

Without knowing codeigniter it would probably look something like:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('job');
$this->db->where_in('id', $functional);
$query = $this->db->get();
```